# how to convert a -ve value to a value with out sign infront of it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am storing -ve and non-sign integer in Database,to depict before i.e. -ve value or after i.e. no sign from some particular reference point.
for e.g. on webpage I would show -5  as before 5 days before separation Date. How to conver that -5 into 5 . Although one way could be to get a substring of -5,but that's a naive one. Is there any better method?

Comment: Caution Downvoter : I didn't find the solution that's why I asked it here.It might seem naive or easy to you,but for me It was still a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**`Math.abs()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) which returns the `absolute value of a number`.

```
Math.abs(-5)
```

**Update:**  Actually I missed it.  Even if it is a string, `math.abs()` converts automatically to number.

```
Math.abs(-5)   //returns 5
Math.abs('-5') //returns 5
```

Comment: that's neat solution. But for that naive approach var stringFromNum="'+numberVariable+'" , would this result in string variable ? Just curious.

Comment: Actually you cannot say or not whether the OP has the value as string or number. Who knows how he gets the data from the database and what he does with it. Either, `Math.abs` is the best method to solve that.

Comment: @FelixKling I mentioned about substring because OP mentioned `Although one way could be to get a substring of -5,but that's a naive one.`

Comment: @Rishi if that the case     `var stringFromNum="-5";
    Math.abs(+stringFromNum);`  adding `+` infront a string varaible convert it to `number` dataType

Comment: I know, I'm just saying you cannot say *"you can't use substring"* because you don't know in which form the value exists. Also I'm pretty sure `Math.abs` converts the argument to a number automatically.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right.  I missed to check it.  Thanks for letting me know this.  `Math.abs('-5')` returns 5

Answer (score 1):

please use Math.abs(-16) to get only 16. Otherwise you could create a function that returns positive value, inside the function set logic that if input argument is positive, return it otherwise multiply with -1 and then return (in case you dont want to use Math.abs() this predefined function. any issues ?

Comment: multiply with -1 ,oh that's so simple. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Absolute function from Math header.

```
var num = -20;
num = Math.abs(num);
```

This will convert the number to absolute value (ie.) positive number.